# Cannot invoke "com.nadjibi.pump.entities.Equipment.setCommand(String)" because "e" is null

Tags: java

```java
@Override
public boolean changeEquipmentCmd( String serialNumber, String cmd )
{
  Equipment e = equipmentRepository.findEquipmentBySerialNumber( serialNumber );
  e.setCommand( cmd );
  equipmentRepository.save( e );
  return true;
}

@RequestMapping( value = "/equipment/changeCmd", method = RequestMethod.PUT )
public boolean changeEquipmentCmd( @RequestParam( "sn" ) String serialNumber, @RequestParam( "cmd" ) String cmd ) 
{
  return iotMetier.changeEquipmentCmd( serialNumber, cmd );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's so difficult in understanding the error message?

`e` is `null` in the call to `e.setCommand( cmd );`.

That's because the call to `equipmentRepository.findEquipmentBySerialNumber( serialNumber );` returns `null`.

Why that call returns `null`… well, that is another question.

Comment: what I don't understand is why it returns null

Comment: @BoucountaBa – As said: that is another question! One that cannot be answered without knowing the specification of `findEquipmentBySerialNumber()` and its implementation; also useful would be the value of `serialNumber` and whether that value exists in the data that is search by `findEquipmentBySerialNumber()`.